# Change phoenix endpoint url host at runtime

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

Does anyone know of a way of changing the `:host` of the Phoenix application endpoint dynamically on every request?

Specifically to support multiple domains on a single phoenix app, i want to change the host in the endpoint based on the host in the connection object.

Am trying something on the lines of

```
conn = Map.get_and_update(conn.private.phoenix_endpoint[:url], :host, fn (_) -> "ll.com" end)
```

or

```
Keyword.put(conn.private.phoenix_endpoint.config(:url), :host, conn.host)
```

But am not quite correct.

Comment: Is changing `conn.host` (using e.g. `conn = %{conn | host: "ll.com"}`) not enough for your use case?

Comment: That does not change the host in the redirects.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it just be a value you assign the `:to` keyword in the redirect?

```
def index(conn, params) do
  redirect conn, to: params[:location] # or whatever
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The [master_proxy](https://github.com/jesseshieh/master_proxy) package offers some useful tools to support multiple sites.